AUTOSAR based application software component for reading CAN messages
I am new to AUTOSAR and COM stack. I am trying to write arxml file for application software component that will receive one CAN message asynchronously and do the decoding. ID is 0x500, DLC is 8 and there are two signals, cmd1 (first 2 bits) and cmd2 (second 2 bits). How to connect this component to the COM module in BSW layer? Do I need signals, or group signals?
Thanks in advance!

That's a lot of individual questions that would require a long-form text to really explain the details. I'll restrict myself to some short hints:

Writing ARMXL in a text editor is a bag of hurt, especially on beginner level. ARXML is a serialization format for AUTOSAR tools. You'd be better off using a design and configuration tool rather than being exposed to ARXML directly.
The CAN ID and DLC are subject to the CAN Driver module. An application software-component does not get anywhere near the CAN-ID (yes, there is an exception, but that’s not relevant for beginners).
If I get your description correctly, you don't need signal groups.
If you are serious about getting into AUTOSAR, please do yourself a favor and attend a professional training class to achieve an in-depth understanding of the overall approach. This will answer all your questions, but it takes time and effort to get to the bottom of it.

